# How to skip one page from iterations?

Tags: python, scrapy

How can skip one iteration of spider if the webpage contains some data?

## Page titles:

We have several page title on pages. I skip other data (dates, likes).

```
page 1 title: 'We like cats'  # this title is valid
page 2 title: 'This title contains WORD X...'  # this title is not valid (skip it)
page 3 title: 'Best ideas'  # this title is valid
```

## Code:

```py
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider

class Carflix(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'carflix'
    allowed_domains = ['sitex.com']
    start_urls = ['http://sitex.com/page-1.html',
                  'http://sitex.com/page-2.html',
                  'http://sitex.com/page-2.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        date = response.xpath('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract_first()
        pagetitle = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()
        if 'WORD X' in pagetitle:
            # what need to do that skip adding data if page title contains 'WORD X'
        likes = response.xpath('//div[@class="likes"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield{
            'pagetitle': pagetitle,
            'date': date,
            'likes': likes,
        }
```

## The result should be:

````
[{
    'pagetitle': 'We like cats',
    'date': '01/01/2019',
    'likes': 200
},
{
    'pagetitle': 'Best ideas',
    'date': '02/01/2019',
    'likes': 100
}]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just yield your results under your specified condition:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    date = response.xpath('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract_first()
    pagetitle = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()
    likes = response.xpath('//div[@class="likes"]/text()').extract_first()
    if not 'WORD X' in pagetitle:
        yield {
          'pagetitle': pagetitle,
          'date': date,
          'likes': likes,
         }
```

Comment: It was so simple...) Need more rest.

Comment: If the spider has a lot of field for parse, can I interrupt the current iteration to continue with the next iteration that to minimize the load?

Comment: Just extract the title as the very first action every iteration and immediately return from your parse function if the title does not match your specified criteria. Only extract the other information if you really need it.